# Access array of type integer from Field through java reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

Say i have this class

```
public static final class MyClass { 

    public static final int A = 4 ;

    public static final int[] B = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
}
```

I have to access above class and its field values through reflections

```
Class<?> myClass = getDesiredClass("MyClass");
```

I am able to get the value of A by this

```
int a = myClass.getField("A").getInt(myClass);
```

But how to get value of B, what methods of Field should i use?

```
 int[] b = myClass.getField("B").?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `int[]` is an `Object`, so just use `(int[]) get(myClass)` -- or alternatively, `(int[]) get(null)`, since no argument is needed for static fields.

Answer (score 2):

All these are equivalent. I would pick the simplest. ;)

```
int[] b = MyClass.B;
int[] b = (int[]) MyClass.class.getField("B").get(null);
int[] b = (int[]) Class.forName("MyClass").getField("B").get(null);
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply too and detail explanation.